# Slim php API setStatus not working

Tags: php, http-headers, slim

I want to set my http response header via the SLIM-php framework. E.g. using

```
$app->response->setStatus('403');
```

On my local apache2 it's running perfectly, but when I put it on live server I always get `Status 200 OK`.

On local I run a php-5.4.6 but live there is just php 5.3.28 could that be a reason? I also access the API via sub domain from another provider. 
I tested a lot of things, also setting the header directly with php `header()` function is not working.
Any one has any idea where could be the failure?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Slim docs](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Response-Status), use an Integer to set the status.

So
`$app->response->setStatus(403);`
should work.

Comment: I changed it in code but it makes no difference. I think it's some hoster problem.

Answer (score 0):

Request and Response objects are Immutable in Slim
basically you need to do this ugly thing:

```
$app->response = $app->response->setStatus('403');
```